# Why won't scale_fill_stepsn work with my data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get `scale_fill_stepsn` to work with my data. I want 7 binned colors, which I am providing. I keep getting either some weird version of my colors (which is bad), fewer than 7 bins or something just doesn't work. It *does* work with the default breaks, but unfortunately those breaks don't result in a lot of variation (I'd like to have roughly the same number of points in each bin).

If I plot using this code, it gets 7 different colors, but they're not the colors I specified:

```
  pal <- c("#EDF8FB", "#BFD3E6", "#9EBCDA", "#8C96C6", "#8C6BB1", "#88419D", "#6E016B")
  data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(161, .04, .02), y = rnorm(161, .04, .02),
            col = c(0.164, 0.163, 0.128, 0.124, 0.123, 0.121, 0.12, 0.111, 0.105, 
                    0.104, 0.104, 0.103, 0.1, 0.1, 0.093, 0.089, 0.089, 0.088, 0.086, 
                    0.084, 0.084, 0.083, 0.083, 0.082, 0.081, 0.077, 0.075, 0.075, 
                    0.074, 0.074, 0.073, 0.072, 0.072, 0.072, 0.071, 0.07, 0.069, 
                    0.069, 0.068, 0.067, 0.067, 0.066, 0.066, 0.066, 0.064, 0.063, 
                    0.063, 0.063, 0.062, 0.061, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.059, 0.059, 0.058, 
                    0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 0.056, 0.056, 0.055, 0.054, 0.054, 
                    0.052, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.05, 0.049, 0.049, 
                    0.049, 0.049, 0.048, 0.048, 0.047, 0.047, 0.047, 0.047, 0.047, 
                    0.046, 0.045, 0.045, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.043, 0.043, 
                    0.043, 0.043, 0.042, 0.042, 0.042, 0.042, 0.042, 0.042, 0.041, 
                    0.041, 0.041, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.039, 
                    0.039, 0.039, 0.038, 0.038, 0.037, 0.037, 0.036, 0.036, 0.036, 
                    0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.034, 0.034, 0.033, 0.033, 0.033, 
                    0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.03, 
                    0.03, 0.029, 0.029, 0.028, 0.028, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.025, 
                    0.023, 0.023, 0.022, 0.022, 0.021, 0.021, 0.02, 0.016, 0.016, 
                    0.015, 0.015, 0.01, 0.009, 0.004))
  
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = col), size = 10, pch = 21) +
    scale_fill_stepsn(colors = pal, n.breaks = 7, breaks = 1:6 * .01)
```

[image: Plot 1]

It may be easier to see what's happening if you change to a different palette:

```
pal <- c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3", "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628")
```

[image: Plot2]

So it's blending the first 4 colors or something like that and then using the maximum color. It doesn't happen on fake data, so it's obviously related to this particular dataset. Any ideas of how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the breaks to be set at your maximum and minimum values, and you need 8 of them (the length of your palette + 1). This will divide your colours into 7 groups with equal ranges.

To specify that you don't want the colors interpolated, you need to map them to the centre of each bin. You can use the `values` argument for this, which maps values between 0 and 1 onto the scale. The first point should be halfway between 0 and 1/7, the second halfway between 1/7 and 2/7, etc.

Personally, I would probably use `cut` on the `col` values and use `scale_fill_manual`, but here's how to do it with `scale_fill_stepsn`

```r
ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = col), size = 10, pch = 21) +
    scale_fill_stepsn(colors = pal, 
                      breaks = seq(min(data$col), max(data$col), length = 8),
                      values = seq(1/14, 13/14, length = 7))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To calculate the values for any set of breaks correctly, you can use these two helper functions:

```r
get_breaks <- function(vec, breaks) {
  c(min(vec), breaks, max(vec))
}

get_values <- function(vec, breaks) {
  breaks <- get_breaks(vec, breaks)
  vals <- (diff(breaks)/2 + head(breaks, -1) - min(breaks))/diff(range(vec))
  vals[length(vals)] <- vals[length(vals)] + .Machine$double.eps
  vals
}
```

Which allow:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = col), size = 10, pch = 21) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = pal, 
                    breaks = get_breaks(data$col, 1:6 * 0.01),
                    values = get_values(data$col, 1:6 * 0.01))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I definitely have used `cut` in the past, but I really wanted it to have the colorbar legend with the breakpoints labelled. This is definitely closer, but when I try to actually assign the breakpoints I want (i.e. min, 0.01 * 1:6, max), I'm getting two greys at the bottom. So frustrating!

Comment: @Caroline you can have whatever break points you like as long as the values match up.

Comment: @Caroline see my update - I have written a function that will take your sequence of breaks and map it to the correct values. The break bar now looks as expected, with all your selected breaks in the right places.